# storing array index value in a variable/ using it directly with index number ... why the answers are different?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, c++14

In the code given below, inside the if condition, when I'm using input[i] instead of 'current' I'm getting a different answers ...
Why ?
When both the values accesses the same index and are exactly same.

Example -
for the array - 1 7 4 0 9 4
with input[i] I'm getting - 1 4 0 7 4 9 (incorrect output)
and with current I'm getting - 0 1 4 4 7 9 (correct output)

```
void insertionSort(int *input, int size)
{
    int j;
    for(int i=1; i<size; i++){
        int current = input[i];
        for(j=i-1; j>=0; j--){
            if(current < input[j]){
                input[j+1] = input[j];
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
        input[j+1] = current;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you modify `input[i]`?

Answer (score 0):

Because while shifting the elements in nested `for` loop, `input[i]` may get modified.
Check this statement of `if` block of nested `for` loop:

```
input[j+1] = input[j];
```

`j` is initialised with `i-1`, so

```
j+1  =>  i-1+1  =>  i
```

That means, in the first iteration, `input[j+1]` is referring to same element in array as `input[i]`. If you use `input[i]` in nested `for` loop `if` condition and if, assume in first iteration, `input[i]` is less than `input[j]`, the `if` condition will result in `true` and `input[i]` gets modified:

```
            if(input[i] < input[j]){   //input[i] is used in place of 'current'
                input[j+1] = input[j];
```

and in further iterations, the comparison will happen with the modified value of `input[i]`, which will lead to wrong result.

If `current` is used for comparison in nested `for` loop `if` condition, `input[j]` will be compared with same value in every iteration of nested `for` loop which is the expected behaviour in insertion sort.